# Xubuntu removal

Tags: xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu over Ubuntu 20.01, would like to uninstall it, it doesn't boot into Ubuntu, only Xubuntu. I didn't really like the look. New user, learning. I couldn't find the command to use. thx.

Comment: How did you "install xubuntu over ubuntu"? Now you can install ubuntu over xubuntu the same way I guess ;-)

Comment: How you remove software depends entirely upon how you installed it. Please [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1245939/edit) to list the steps you took or link to the instructions you followed.

Comment: You may want to clarify you question, there was no 2020-January release of Ubuntu (all Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format),  If you added a second desktop to your system (and you're talking about 20.04 or 2020-April release) then at login you can select if you want to use GNOME (Ubuntu) or XFCE (Xubuntu), and to switch just means you need to logout & select the other DEsktop. Your question however is unclear, install?  as it `apt install` to add to your existing or install from CD/thumb-drive thus replace??

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed using `tasksel` you might try:

1. Set `gdm3` as the default window manager

Type: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and pick `gdm3` as the default

2. Ensure `gnome-session` is the x-session-manager

Type: `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager`.

```
lab@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
There are 5 choices for the alternative x-session-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-session-manager).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gnome-session     50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-session     50        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/openbox-session   40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/startlxqt         50        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/startxfce4        50        manual mode
* 5            /usr/bin/xfce4-session     40        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Pick `0` to set `gnome-session`

This should be enough to get you booting Ubuntu Desktop again if you rebooted.

3. Uninstall Xubuntu

You can try `tasksel`

Type: `sudo tasksel` and deselect Xubuntu Desktop and Xubuntu. This might give you an error like `tasksel: apt-get failed (100)`.

If it does, you can still remove a good number of packages related to Xubuntu and xfce using the following.

Type: `sudo apt purge xubuntu-* xfce* plymouth-theme-*`

See also: https://itsfoss.com/install-xfce-desktop-xubuntu/